# Problems with storing array of strings, and parsing through each string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Okay so Basically my program begins by taking a users input. The input begins with an integer n specifying the number of commands to follow. After that line there will be n lines with a command on each line. I am trying to store each of these commands as a string in a string array, and then I am trying to process each string to find out what type of command it is and what numbers the user inputs on that same line.

Example Input:

> ./a
>
> 2
>
> I 1 2
>
> I 2 3

I want my program to then store each line, under the first input(2), into a string array. I then try to process each letter, and number in that single line.

My current code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int number_of_insertions;
cin >> number_of_insertions;
cin.ignore();

string commandlist[number_of_insertions];

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_insertions; i++) {
    string command;
    getline(cin, command);
    commandlist[i] = command;
}


string command;
char operation;
int element;
int index;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_insertions; i++) {
    command = commandlist[i].c_str();
    operation = command[0];

    switch(operation) {
        case 'I':
            element = (int) command[1];
            index = (int) command[2];
            cout << "Ran insertion. Element = " << element << ", and Index = " << index << endl;
            break;
        case 'D':
            index = command[1];
            cout << "Ran Delete. Index = " << index << endl;
            break;
        case 'S':
            cout << "Ran Print. No variables" << endl;
            break;
        case 'P':
            index = command[1];
            cout << "Ran print certain element. Index = " << index << endl;
            break;
        case 'J':
        default:
            cout << "Invalid command" << endl;

    }
 }  
}
```

And then my output for the example input is as follows:

> Ran insertion. Element = 32, and Index = 49
>
> Ran insertion. Element = 32, and Index = 50

Not sure at all how to fix this problem, and looking forward to receiving some help from everybody.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
        element = (int) command[1];
        index = (int) command[2];
```

don't convert the second and third tokens of `command` to an integer. They just take the integer values of the second and third characters of `command` and assign them to `element` and `index`, respectively.

What you need to do is extract tokens from `command` using some sort of parsing mechanism.

```
std::istringstream str(command);
char c;
str >> c; // That would be 'I'.

str >> element;
str >> index;
```

etc.